# where is the systemout log of websphere on docker?

Tags: logging, docker, websphere

I have docker installed on top of Centos 7. Then I have the websphere-liberty image. On top of the WAS image, I created my application image. When I run the application, I got an error page. I see some errors on the console with "docker logs...". But I am trying to find more details in the SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log. I just couldn't find them under /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/logs or anywhere else after entering the "docker exec -it  /bin/bash".

Please help.

Comment: Liberty doesn't have a SystemOut and SystemErr.log. There is messages.log and console.log. Have you looked for those?

Comment: I see the /logs/messages.log, which has quite some information. I couldn't find the console.log though. Where to find it? Thanks Alasdair.

Comment: `console.log` is in the same folder as `messages.log`, but may not be always created, depending how you start your server e.g. if you do `server run serverName` then there is no console log as its contents are outputted to the screen directly.